# How to find the IP of a user in a JS based chat room?

Tags: javascript

What is the algorithm or the code to find the IP of a user while in a javascript based chatroom?

logging into one such room and i am told that someone knows my IP and also the OS i am using just by inserting a simple JS based code in the original site code withouth any illegal doing.....

help me out i am just curious.

Thanks!

Comment: That will very much depend on the chatroom in question. There is no general answer that applies to all chat rooms equally.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

He most likely inserted an `<img>` tag pointing to a script that displays the IP and user agent of whoever requested it. This is actually a common joke in forum signatures etc. to confuse people not knowing it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [danasoft.com](http://www.danasoft.com/vipersig.jpg))</sub>

Unless the script is logging IPs or he's monitoring the logfiles of the server where the script is located he cannot actually see your IP address.